# Como retorna um boolean no button

Tags: java, if, javafx, condição

Eu tenho um `button` e quero que quando ele for clicado retorne `true` em um `if` de outra classe, mas não encontrei nenhum método de como faço isso.

```
Button b = new Button();
```

Outra classe:

```
public static ObservableList getObs(ObservableList<String> obs,ObservableList<String> obs2){ 
    if(Main.b.algumMetodo() == true){
        return obs2;
    }else if(Main.b.algumMetodo() != true){
        return obs;
    }
    return obs;
}
```

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para receber uma notificacão quando o botão for clicado:

```
     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Acão, código aqui é executado.
         }
     });
```

Edit:

O problema é que o botão só vai estar no estado de clicado uns millisegundos - então a menos que esteja chamando a funcão muito frequentemente a probabilidade de estar true é muito, muito baixa.

O qué poderia fazer é colocar um proprio `boolean` no `OnClickListener` onde você pode mudar o estado como queira (depois de um segundo? 10 segundos? com `Thread.sleep()`, em um proprio `Thread`, sei lá o que é preciso. Depois da outra funcão ser evaluida?).

Comment: Mas não da para fazer disso porque dentro do if vai ter que retorna um ObservableList, vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade o o meu problema é que ele não consegue trocar os ObservableList

Comment: Editei a resposta também. Boa sorte!

Comment: O que é esse `View v`? Não é Swing isso?

Comment: É o botão que foi clicado.

Comment: Desculpe, mas ainda não entendi. Mas só re-explicando eu quero que quando eu clicar no botão ele retorne o obs(ObservableList) e se eu clicar novamente retorne o outro ObservableList(obs2).

Comment: Deu certo, fiz do jeito que você disse e consegui, Obrigado!